# What function would I create to best fit this line.

Tags: functions

I'm trying to create a function to smoothly match [this line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz0XY.png).

**Function description:**

When `0` is the input, I want `1` to be the output.

The line quickly slopes downward at the beginning and end, and slowly slopes downward in the middle.

When `1` is the input, I want `0` to be the output.

Thanks!

Comment: Your picture shows it sloping slowly at the beginning.  Based on the verbal description you might consider a rescaling the $\arccos$ function, like $y=\dfrac{\arccos(2x-1)}{\pi}$

Comment: This looks like the Cumulative distribution function for the normal distribution but done backwards.

Comment: @JonasMeyer The function looks good, but I would like the beginning and end of the line to slope quickly for a little longer, and the middle of the line to not be so sloped. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: $y=\dfrac{\arccos\left(1-2\frac{\arccos(2x-1)}{\pi}\right)}{\pi}$?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes, thanks so much! If you put that in an answer I will accept it and up vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe sounds somewhat like $\arccos$, which ordinarily takes $[-1,1]$ to $[0,\pi]$, but can be moved to fit the values: $y=f(x)=\dfrac{\arccos(2x-1)}{\pi}$. In order to exaggerate the effect, once you have one good approximation, you can flip it upside down and apply it again, $y=f(1-f(x))=\dfrac{\arccos\left(1-2\frac{\arccos(2x-1)}{\pi}\right)}{\pi}$.

It was commented that that suffices.  If wanting it even more exaggerated, we can do the same thing again:

$y=f(1-f(1-f(x)))=\dfrac{\arccos\left(1-2\dfrac{\arccos\left(1-2\frac{\arccos(2x-1)}{\pi}\right)}{\pi}\right)}{\pi}$.

The following Desmos graph shows the first 4 iterations.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks so much!!!! I can't up-vote it because I'm under 15 reputation but I will when I can.